# How can I use tf.cond?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to get the result from model using condition statement.
There are 3 tensors all has the same shape:  `mu, sigma, alpha`. 
Among them, if `alpha[:, -1]` has a probability of zero, I want to get the 0 value. Specifically, if `alpha[:, -1]` is bigger than 0.5, and other value when `alpha[:, -1]` is smaller than 0.5.
This is my code.

```
def get_mdn_result(self, params):
    # ouput of each step -> params : 2d
    mu = params[:, :self.num_mixture]
    sigma = params[:, self.num_mixture:self.num_mixture * 2]
    alpha = params[:, self.num_mixture * 2:self.num_mixture * 3]

    mu = tf.reduce_sum(mu * alpha, 1, keepdims=True)
    sigma = tf.reduce_sum(sigma**2 * alpha**2, 1, keepdims=True)

    mu = tf.cond(alpha[:, -1] < 0.5, lambda: tf.reduce_sum(mu * alpha, 1, keepdims=True), lambda: 0)

    return mu, sigma
```

but I've got an error message like below.

> Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'while/cond/Switch' (op:
>   'Switch') with input shapes: [?], [?].

How I can fix it?

mu, alpha are like this

```
mu

[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

alpha

[[0.1, 0.3, 0.6],[0.5, 0.2, 0.3]]
```

Comment: What shapes do your values have? Can you provide more details on the surrounding setup?